# Do not need Git Synchronization

Tags: eclipse, git

I know this is a foolish question. When I do a git compare (Project -> Right click -> Compare with), comparison opens in Synchronization panel instead of Compare window panel.

I am unable to understand git synchronization and thus not able to compare my branches.

I don't want git synchronization window panel. I need a git compare tree panel.

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

The [synchronization (since Egit 3.1)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Comparing_with_Branches_.28Synchronize.29) is for **the difference between the working tree (including not committed changes) and a branch or tag**.

As mentioned in "[Compare editor and Synchronize View](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Compare_editor_and_Synchronize_View)":

> **If you use any of the submenu actions of Compare With on a single file, a compare editor will be shown, otherwise (since EGit 3.1) the Synchronize View will be opened** that lets you browse the changes;
>   **by double-clicking on a changed file in this view, a compare editor will be opened for this file**.
>   In the toolbar of the Synchronize View you can select the Sychronize Model you want to use for presenting the changes you are inspecting.

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/1/11/Egit-3.1-SynchronizeSwitchModel.png]

---

To get only a compare view, you can also follow the section "[Compare working tree with last commit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Compare_working_tree_with_last_commit)":

> The difference between a resource in the current working directory and in the last commit in the current branch can be viewed from the context menu **`Compare With > HEAD revision`**.
>   This feature is also available in the Commit dialog.
>   **Double clicking on an entry in the Commit dialog opens a compare dialog**.

Comment: Thank you VonC. I have read this document before and it really didn't solved my problem. I think this is something to do with Git version. Git have by default added this in their new version(since EGit 3.1).

Comment: @SuburbSanyaasi yes, 3.1 introduces an extra step: first Synchronisation view, then click on a git commit to access the comparison view.